# Accessing a file from Sharepoint library from iOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, sharepoint

I would like to know whether it is possible to access an image stored in SharePoint library programmatically from iOS app.
Defined it as a URL. In the URLSessionDelegate gave the  authentication method as NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust and valid credentials.

In the completion handler, i am getting error as nil.
But response says -  Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically

Is it really possible to access image from sharepoint this way, without using graph api?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not authenticating properly. Here is a URLSessionDelegate function in swift which checks the authentication method in the challenge. It normally should be NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM for sharepoint sites.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    guard challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 else {
        print("too many failures")
        challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }

    guard challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM else {
        print("unknown authentication method \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")
        challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }

    guard self.doesHaveCredentials() else {
        challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Userdata not set")
        };
        return
    }

    let credentials = URLCredential(user: self.username!, password: self.password!, persistence: .forSession)
    challenge.sender?.use(credentials, for: challenge)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, credentials)
}
```

This was taken from https://gist.github.com/stevenschobert/f374c999e5cba6ccf09653b846967c83 which has a good example of NTLM authentication using swift.

Comment: I had tried this. Could not post a detailed comment.Hence posted as an answer. Please check.